# New York City was cleared to move dozens of homeless men

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "NYC was cleared" mean "NYC was free from suspicion or guilt"?

> The New York Times tweeted just now:
>
> After a nearly yearlong battle, **New York City was cleared to move dozens of homeless men** out of an Upper West Side hotel. But the city said it would let the men stay there until plans for a larger move of over 9,000 homeless people takes place.

[Source](https://twitter.com/nytimes/status/1400630913139105793)

Comment: If you substitute the definition for the word, the sentence makes no sense. After a yearlong battle, New Yuck City was free of guilt to move…That is a clue that this definition can’t possibly be right.

Comment: There's a typical headline-writer's ambiguity here that's entertaining - you could read it as "NYC was emptied", which would of course move dozens of homeless men!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is definition 52 of *clear* on [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/clear2):

> to give clearance to; authorize

The city government was given authorization or permission to move the homeless men.

Answer (score 3):

No, *cleared* means "Give official approval or authorization to" ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/clear)). As stated in the article preview, it was the courts who made the decision to allow the city to do this. (Note that the original sentence is in the passive.)